# How do I send an attention-mask "Mask" matrix in transformer encoder along with my latent in pytorch's nn.TransformerEncoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I have a transformer_encoder initialized in pytorch as:

```
transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=input_dim, nhead=num_heads), num_layers=num_layers)
```

Now I have a latent, which is of shape [8, 320, 512], where 8 is the batch_size, 320 is the sequence length, and 512 is the embedding dimension.

I also have an attention mask of shape [320, 320].

And I want to pass it into transformer encoder like:

```
latent = torch.rand(8, 320, 512)
mask = torch.rand(320, 320)

output = transformer_encoder(latent, mask)
```

But it is giving me error:
"The shape of the 2D attn_mask is torch.Size([320, 320]), but should be (8, 8)."
Now I repeated the matrix along batch dimension creating 8 of those (320, 320) matrices, making the shape of 'mask', [8, 320, 320]. When I ran again the above code

```
latent.shape = [8, 320, 512]
mask.shape = [8, 320, 320]

output = transformer_encoder(latent, mask)
```

It gives me this error:
"The shape of the 3D attn_mask is torch.Size([8, 320, 320]), but should be (2560, 8, 8)."

Can someone explain what is the problem here? And how can I solve it? Or the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

your mask is not correctly set. you have a batch size of 8 and a sequence length of 320. try adding:

```
mask = torch.ones(8, 320, 320)
mask = mask.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
```

before using:

```
output = transformer_encoder(latent, mask)
```